# Moment.js: Convert from date string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

How do I get month and year from date like "Apr 2015" or "Dec 2016" with moment.js?

I tried using this, but it returns NaN:

```
var date = 'Apr 2016';
console.log(moment(date).get('month')); // I want it to return 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the date format explicitly when [parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) a non ISO 8601 string or a string not recognized by `new Date(string)`. Increment the result by one, as the [range](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) is 0 … 11:

```
moment('Apr 2016', 'MMM YYYY').get('month') + 1 // = 4
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what i want